# Laravel error (Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value)

Tags: php, forms, laravel, date, laravel-5

I`m trying to create page for add user details to database via form values.it gives me this error when I press the submit button.

[image]

Here is my migration field.

```
 $table->date('gce_ol_year');
```

Here is the relevant form attribute

```
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>GCE(O/L) Year:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="gce_ol_year" type="month" value="2011-08" id="example-month-input">
  </div>
```

Here is the relevant controller attribute

```
$item ->gce_ol_year = $request ->gce_ol_year;
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Well, `08/2011` is an invalid datetime format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller add Carbon

```
$item->gce_ol_year = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->gce_ol_year);
```

If it still does not work, fix the value in your input value to include the day like `value="2011-08-01"`.

WHY?

Because your input is of Datetime format. If you want to only save the year, change your migration from `$table->datetime('gce_ol_year')` to `$table->string('gce_ol_year')`. If you don't want to use a string, `integer` could also work.